# ColdFusion dynamic thread names

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How can I access a dynamic thread name in ColdFusion? Normally if I'm using a dynamic variable name, I'd do something like this:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter" > 
    <cfset Names[counter] = rereplace( createUUID(), "[-_\.]", "", "all") />
    <cfset something[ Names[counter] ] = 1 />
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
    #( something[ Names[1] ] + something[ Names[2] ] + something[ Names[3] ]  )#
</cfoutput>
```

However, trying to do this with threads seems trickier, as I can't find a way to instantiate them besides using `<cfthread>`, which doesn't want to allow me to create a thread as a struct member. Here's what I've tried:

**Attempt 1**

```
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter" > 
    <cfset ThreadNames[counter] = rereplace( createUUID(), "[-_\.]", "", "all") />
    <cfthread action="run" name="#something[ ThreadNames[counter] ]#" > 
        <cfset Thread.something = 1 />
    </cfthread>
</cfloop>
```

> Element ... is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.

This one gets as far as the output before throwing an error.  I didn't really expect the thread to be in the variables scope, but I can't specify the scope and I also can't find what scope it's built into. In short, I can't figure out how to access the thread from there:

**Attempt 2**

```
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter" > 
    <cfset ThreadNames[counter] = rereplace( createUUID(), "[-_\.]", "", "all") />
    <cfthread action="run" name="#ThreadNames[counter]#" > 
        <cfset Thread.something = 1 />
    </cfthread>
</cfloop>

<cfthread action="join" name="#ThreadNames[1]#, #ThreadNames[2]#, #ThreadNames[3]#" />

<cfoutput>
    #( VARIABLES[ThreadNames[1]].something  + VARIABLES[ThreadNames[2]].something  + VARIABLES[ThreadNames[3]].something  )#
</cfoutput>
```

> Element ... is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.VariableScope.

**Non-dynamic Example**

For reference, here's how the code looks before trying to throw in the uuids

```
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter" > 
    <cfthread action="run" name="thread#counter#" > 
        <cfset Thread.something = 1 />
    </cfthread>
</cfloop>

<cfthread action="join" name="thread1, thread2, thread3" />

<cfoutput>
    #( thread1.something  + thread2.something  + thread3.something  )#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You can’t access threads like that. You can join a thread after it completes, but you cannot simply write to a variable inside a running thread unless it is in a shared scope (like application or session), but you better be careful even doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Variables created inside of threads have their own scope that can be accessed after they're joined.

Comment: your example is just wrong. I’m not sure what you’re trying to do when you execute thread[name].variableName = 1; Maybe you could explain what you’re trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated this answer in order to simplify my example. Previously, I had stored the thread name in an application variable key. This is unneccessary unless, you wish to store the values globally. The 'variables' scope is quite sufficient.

**Important:**

When you use the 'run' action, it is a 'set & forget' action. Any thread scoped variables created cannot be accessed externally, unless the thread is joined.
An alternative approach is to create variables in a shared scope, like the 'application' or 'session' scope. Any changes made to a shared scope variable from within a thread can be accessed externally.

**Implementation:**

Access the thread name by passing it in, using the 'attributes' scope. By storing the thread name within the thread, you can ensure that the thread has executed and will exist, at the time the threads are joined.

```
<cfset variables.threadNames = {} />

<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter" > 
  <cfset variables.threadName = REReplace(CreateUUID(), "[-]", "", "all") />
  <cfthread action="run" name="#variables.threadName#" threadName="#variables.threadName#" counter="#counter#"> 
    <cfset thread.something = attributes.counter />
    <cfset variables.threadNames[attributes.threadName] = thread.something />
  </cfthread>
</cfloop>

<cfthread action="join" name="#StructKeyList(variables.threadNames)#" timeout="6000" />

<cfloop collection="#variables.threadNames#" item="key">
  <cfset variables.thread = cfthread[key]>
  <cfdump var="#variables.thread#" />
</cfloop>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question; You just dumped `variables.lckThreadName`, but how I can I access, say, the value of the 4th thread created? I can't use `#variables.lckThreadName[4]#`.  

Also, `You need to understand that you cannot access the 'thread' scope from outside the thread itself, but you could pass it into a shared scope, like the 'application' or 'session' scope.` isn't exactly true, that's why I joined them, and once they're joined to the main thread their scopes are accessible.

Comment: OK. So you could extract the name from the application variable key or you could add the thread name to the application value itself.

Comment: I believe I tried that already, I may not have included it in the examples I put in my question though.

Comment: To be honest, I, initially, did not see the 'join', however my example does work, as I have tested it.

Comment: cfthread[key] is what I was looking for. I didn't know they could be accessed this way. Thanks. Can I ask where you found that? If it's in the coldfusion docs, I've overlooked it.

Comment: Well. CFTHREAD is a just a structure, so it can accept a key from a 'collection' loop, and because both keys match...volia!

Comment: Actually, Ben Nadel taught me that CFTHREAD is a structure. Kind of neat...

Comment: Not sure what you are gaining by using cfthread as a struct. Seems unconventional and confusing, not to mention that you have no idea if cfthread will always be a struct. Why not create/manage your own data structure(s)?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean? Maybe, you could add an answer with this alternative methodology? The application variable will only return 'thread' names that exist, so we know these will be structures with identifiable keys.